# While loop causing print statement to print twice

Tags: java, loops, while-loop

My program encrypts and decrypts Caesar Shift codes but the main problem I'm having as of now is that my user selection does not work correctly.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class CaesarShiftTester
{
public static void main(String [] args)
{
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    String message = "";
    String userChoice = "";
    int shift = 0;

    System.out.println("1 - Encrypt\n2 - Decrypt\nQ - Quit Program");
    while(!userChoice.equalsIgnoreCase("Q"))
    {
        System.out.println("Make a selection: ");
        userChoice = in.nextLine();
        if(userChoice.equalsIgnoreCase("1"))
        {
            System.out.print("Please enter a message to be encrypted: ");
            message = in.nextLine();

            System.out.print("Please enter a shift value for the cipher(0 - 25): ");
            shift = in.nextInt();

            CaesarShiftEncryption.genCipherAlphabet(shift);
            System.out.println(CaesarShiftEncryption.encrypt(message));
        }

        else if(userChoice.equalsIgnoreCase("2"))
        {
            System.out.print("Please enter a message to be decrypted: ");
            message = in.nextLine();

            System.out.print("Please enter a shift value for the cipher(0 - 25): ");
            shift = in.nextInt();
        }

        else if(userChoice.equalsIgnoreCase("Q"))
        {
            System.out.println("Thanks for using the program!");
        }
    }
}
}
```

"Make a selection" is being printed twice after the first go through of the program. Here's the other file in the class that doesn't play that big of a role in the problem but is here if you want to test out the files for yourself. Please note I haven't implemented decryption yet so only "1" and "Q" selections actually do anything right now.

```
public class CaesarShiftEncryption
{
private static final String ALPHABET = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";
private static String newAlphabet = "";

public CaesarShiftEncryption()
{

}

public static String genCipherAlphabet(int shift)
{
    for(int i = 0; i < ALPHABET.length(); i++)
    {
        int alphabetShift = i + shift;
        alphabetShift = alphabetShift % 26;
        newAlphabet += ALPHABET.charAt(alphabetShift);
    }
    return newAlphabet;
}

public static String encrypt(String message)
{
    int letter = 0;
    String encoded = "";
    char[] messageLetters = new char[message.length()];

    for(int i = 0; i < message.length(); i++)
    {
        messageLetters[i] = message.charAt(i);
    }

    for(int a = 0; a < message.length(); a++)
    {
        if(Character.isWhitespace(messageLetters[a]))
        {
            encoded += " ";
            a++;
        }

        if(Character.isUpperCase(messageLetters[a]))
            messageLetters[a] = Character.toLowerCase(messageLetters[a]);

        letter = ALPHABET.indexOf(messageLetters[a]);  
        encoded += newAlphabet.substring(letter, letter + 1).toUpperCase();
    }
    return encoded;
}
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure I see the problem, your `System.out.println("Make a selection: ");` is inside the `while` loop, so it could be printed twice, as long as `Q` is not the first input.

Comment: How can I make it display everytime I want the user to be able to choose from the menu of options?

Answer (score 5):

When you read the shift value with

```
shift = in.nextInt();
```

The end of line remains in the scanner. At the next loop iteration this remaining end of line is read but since there was no valid input (1,2, or Q) found, the loop will run again.

To fix that, read your shift value like this:

```
shift = in.nextInt();
in.nextLine();
```